# Automatically hide a control in wpf and claim the space by another control

Tags: wpf, xaml

when I hide the third button , I want the 1st button and 2nd button to be
of more height. I mean, they should claim the space which was occupied by third button when it was visible.
How can I achieve this ?

I am hiding the 3rd button in my xaml.cs file.
Button3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
And based on some condition I hide it. Then my code goes Button3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Grid Grid.Row ="0" x:Name="MyFirstGrid">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button  Name="Button1" Grid.Column="0"   Width="200" Content="Button 1" ></Button>
        <Button  Name="Button2" Grid.Column="1"   Width="200" Content="Button 1" ></Button>

    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="75"  x:Name="MySecondGrid">

        <Button Name="Button3" Height="75" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Button 2" ></Button>

    </Grid>

    <Button Name="Button4" Grid.Row="2" Height="35" Width="200" Visibility="Visible" Content="Button 3" ></Button>
    <Button Name="Button5" Grid.Row="3" Height="35" Width="200" Content="Button 4" ></Button>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Use `Visibility.Collapsed` instead of `Visibility.Hidden` and fix your layout. There's still the Grid with Height=75. Also `Height="Auto"` for the rows won't work.

Comment: Try taking a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437237/WPF-Grid-Column-and-Row-Hiding. You want to hide the row, but you also need the outer container to be of fixed size and Row 0 shouldn't be Auto, but *.

Comment: Hello. You should change your RowDefinitionHeight to something like *. Auto means that the height will adjust to the content,  * means that the height will adjust to the remaining space. And be sure to use Visibility="Collapsed" when you hide your button.

Comment: Can you please use specific sizes for your example? Using Auto size is a bad start when you want to take more space than needed.

Comment: Thanks  a lot Clemens,briantyler,Bob , grek40 for all your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a DockPanel and place the buttons that should take additional size as last child:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="cBoolToVis"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Width="300" Height="180"
               KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                Content="Button 5" Height="35"
                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="5"/>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                Content="Button 4" Height="35"
                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="4"/>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                Content="Button 3" Height="75"
                Visibility="{Binding ElementName=switch,Path=IsChecked,Converter={StaticResource cBoolToVis}}"
                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="3"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Content="Button 1"
                    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="Button 2"
                    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="switch"
                  Content="Show / Hide"
                  IsChecked="True"
                  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="5"/>
</Grid>
```

Hit the `Show / Hide` button to test.

You need to set `Visibility=Collapsed` instead of `Hidden`, otherwise the hidden control will still claim its space.

Comment: Hi Grek, It works good. I would like to know what is the use of KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2".   Also, In my case, I am using complicated controls instead of button 1 and button 2. And it claims the space which was occupied by 3rd button. But now the problem is while the controls expand, it is doing so by flickering. Or In other words, animating. I would like to have a expansion without flickering or without animation. Is it possible ?

Comment: @MuhammadVP I don't even know your controls, so I can't possibly know why they flicker and how to change it. The `KeyboardNavigation` thing is not strictly necessary, but if you use the `Tab` key to navigate between controls you can see the difference. The problem is, the controls that appear at top of the UI appear at bottom of the XAML inside the DockPanel. So their default tab order will not be the same as their UI appearance order.

Comment: I have a square control with close button, so it also goes hidden when i click the close button. And when it gets closed, the button 1 and button 2 claims the space. Lets say this square control is placed just after button 3 in the above code, then when i close this square control, there is no flickering , which means button 1 and button 2 enlarge fast . But I noticed that when the same square control is placed above button 3, then the button 1 and button 2 will expand with flickering. What do u think is the problem ?

Comment: @MuhammadVP I doubt that a well implemented square with a close button would make the UI flicker if I create one for testing - so how is this information supposed to help?